# Getting Android Nave Value Pairs from Node.js server

Tags: javascript, android, node.js

So, here it goes..
I am sending a name value pairs with android to my server

```
httpPost = new HttpPost(param[0]);
List<NameValuePair> nameValuePair = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("query", param[1]));
httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePair));
response = httpclient.execute(httpPost);
```

param[] having the url and the query string i have to send to my server.
No my server is in node.js. I tried sending response and all ignoring the query, Its fine. But I dont know how to get the parameter from the namevaluepairs

request.body.query doesnt work.

What to do?

Answer (score 0):

Never Mind. I used HTTP Get and solved my problems.

```
        List<NameValuePair> nameValuePair = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
        nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("query", param[1]));
        String paramString = URLEncodedUtils.format(nameValuePair, "utf-8");
        String url = param[0]+'?'+ paramString;
        response = httpclient.execute(new HttpGet(url));
```

in client (Android) and

in Server (node)

```
fs = require('fs');
var url = require('url');
var querystring = require('querystring');
function search(request, response) {
    var pquery = querystring.parse(url.parse(request.url).query);
    console.log(pquery);
}
```